# How to perform a 2 sided binomial test with the alternative being larger

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

Given data for two groups:

- Group A: $\left\{ (n_1, s_1), (n_2, s_2), \ldots, (n_k, s_k) \right\}$.
- Group B: $\left\{ (n_1, s_1), (n_2, s_2), \ldots, (n_l, s_l) \right\}$.

Where $n_i$ is the number of trials and $s_i$ is the number of successes.

The assumption is that both are samples from a binomial distribution with unknown $p$.
Namely, each observation in the 2 samples is from a binomial distribution with known $n$ but unknown $p$ yet while the $n$ changes per observation, the $p$ is constant for each group.

I want to apply a binomial test with the assumption $p_B = p_A$.
Yet in Wikipedia I found only a [binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) for one sample versus the hypothesis of $p_0$.

Is there a way to have 2 samples binomial test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ be the number of successes in group $A$, and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_l$ for group $B$. By assumption

$$X_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n_i, \theta_A),\quad i=1,\ldots,k,$$
$$Y_j \sim \text{Binomial}(m_i, \theta_B), \quad j=1,\ldots,l$$
and $X_i$'s are independent, $Y_j$'s are independent and $X_i,Y_j,$ are also independent.

Let $S = \sum_i X_i$, $T = \sum_j Y_j$, $n = \sum_i n_i$ and $m = \sum_j m_j$. Then by the closure properties of the binomial distribution

$$
S \sim \text{Binomial}(n, \theta_A), \quad T \sim \text{Binomial}(m, \theta_B).
$$

Thus the test for $H_0:\theta_A=\theta_B$ boils down to testing for the difference between two binomial samples. This problem can be solved either by a Wald, likelihood ratio test, Rao score test or by an exact $\alpha$-level test. I'll work out the details of the Wald test here.

Let $\hat \theta_A,\hat\theta_B$ be the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $\theta_A$ and $\theta_B$ respectively. Then, by the large sample properties of the MLE, we have

$$
\hat\theta_A\,\dot\sim\, N\left(\theta_A, \frac{\hat\theta_A(1-\hat\theta_A)}{n}\right),\quad \hat\theta_B\,\dot\sim\, N\left(\theta_B, \frac{\hat\theta_B(1-\hat\theta_B)}{m}\right),
$$
and $\hat\theta_A$ is independent from $\hat\theta_B$. By the closure properties of the Normal distribution we have

$$
\hat\theta_A-\hat\theta_B \,\dot\sim\, N\left(\theta_A-\theta_B,\frac{\hat\theta_A(1-\hat\theta_A)}{n}+\frac{\hat\theta_B(1-\hat\theta_B)}{m}\right).
$$

Thus

$$
W = \frac{\hat\theta_A-\hat\theta_B-(\theta_A-\theta_B)}{\left(\frac{\hat\theta_A(1-\hat\theta_A)}{n}+\frac{\hat\theta_B(1-\hat\theta_B)}{m}\right)^{1/2}}\,\dot\sim\, N(0,1).
$$

Here "$\dot\sim$" means "distributed as for large $n+m$".

The Wald test is:

> Reject $H_0:\theta_A-\theta_B$ if $|W^{obs}|>z_{\alpha/2}$

where $W^{obs}$ is $W$ computed at the observed data and $z_{\alpha/2}$ is the upper $\alpha$th quantile of the standard normal distribution.

An approximate test of this kind can be computed with `R` using the `prop.test` command; but see also `chisq.test` for a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test. For an exact test, you can either use Fisher's exact test (`fisher.test`) or have a look at the `exact2x2` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/index.html). I presume that in your case the sample size is sufficiently large so approximate tests, such as the Wald test, will be fine.

Comment: thank you @User1865345 for the advice! I added some details for the sake of completeness.

Comment: This is elaborative. Already upvoted.

Comment: This is great! What would you do for small $m$ and $n$? Say about 10-40?

Comment: @Mark, the usual recommendations are: (i) Fisher's exact test, (ii) chi-squared test plus p-value computed by simulation, (iii) permutation or bootstrap tests. I'd add (iv) exact tests implemented in `exact2x2`; (i) and (ii) may be the easiest to perform.

Comment: Is there a place I can read on (ii)?

Comment: yes, you find all the details at the help page of `chisq.test`.

Comment: @Mark similarly to permutation testing; briefly, you either enumerate or sample from the distribution of the tables given the margins (under the null of homogeneity/independence), calculate the statistic for each table and gather all the statistics with their probabilities (exact or estimated) in order to identify the upper tail of the distribution of the statistic so that p values or critical values can be found, as desired. The discussion in R's `chisq.test` relates to the sampling approach